# Could not find function in r

Tags: r, function, loops, sum, repeat

I have a element 'measure' with 5 values say 10 20 30 40 50 and I am trying to get the sum of the other 4 values for each and every value. So if the selected value is 20 then the sum will be 10+30+40+50 = 130. I am doing this with the 'repeat' loop with 'n' denoting the # of values that is 5 in this case and total is the sum of all 5 values of measure that is 150.

```
`i <- 1
repeat
{
  sum <- total - measure(i);
  print(sum);
  if (i > n)
    break;
}`
```

I am encountering an error "Could not find function measure".

Comment: You need to use `measure[i]` with **square** brackets.  If you use parentheses after a name R assumes you are trying to call a function by that name (hence the error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
dat <- seq(10, 50, 10)
res <- rep(sum(dat), length(dat)) # 5 times 150 = 10 + 20 + 30 + 40 + 50
res <- res - dat # (140 = 150 - 10, 130 = 150 - 20, ..., 100 = 150 - 50)
```

Or even faster using **R** to make the repetition `rep` internally (credits to akrun for this trick)

```
sum(dat) - dat
#[1] 140 130 120 110 100
```

Comment: Vectorized. Best answer!

Comment: Thank you !! Easiest and simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 v1 <- seq(10,50, by=10)
 sapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) sum(v1[-i]))
 #[1] 140 130 120 110 100
```

Comment: Elegant way to loop over index instead of elements!

Comment: Your function is more compact

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a for loop, using the `apply` family fonction is recommended for readability (and a really tiny gain of speed depending on the problem). Just do:

```
x = seq(10,50,10)

sapply(x, function(u) sum(x[x!=u]))
#[1] 140 130 120 110 100
```